# Is $on and $broadcast in different controllers possible

Tags: angularjs-scope

Is it possible to put `$scope.broadcast` and `$scope.$on` in different controller? I'm trying to make a global search wherein once I enter a text, the data will direct to the controller responsible for searching. I'm advised to use `$scope.broadcast` and `$scope.$on` just so to transfer data. By the way, I'm an intern... Thank you.

Comment: you can use `$rootScope.on` & `$scope.emit` to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course! 
Using $scope.$emit will fire an event up the $scope. 
Using $scope.$broadcast will fire an event down the $scope. 
Using $scope.$on is how we listen for these events.

The simplest way to emulate parent and child scopes are to use Controllers. Each Controller creates new $scope, which Angular neatly outputs an ng-scope class on newly scoped elements for us:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as parent" class="ng-scope">
  {{ parent.data }}
  <div ng-controller="SiblingOneCtrl as sib1" class="ng-scope">
      {{ sib1.data }}
  </div>
</div>
```

We could fire an event down from ParentCtrl to SiblingOneCtrl using $broadcast:

```
app.controller('ParentCtrl',
  function ParentCtrl ($scope) {

  $scope.$broadcast('parent', 'Some data'); // going down!

});

app.controller('SiblingOneCtrl',
  function SiblingOneCtrl ($scope) {

  $scope.$on('parent', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data); // 'Some data'
  });

});
```

If we wanted to communicate upwards, from SiblingOneCtrl to ParentCtrl, you guessed it, we can use $emit.

```
app.controller('ParentCtrl',
  function ParentCtrl ($scope) {

  $scope.$on('child', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data); // 'Some data'
  });

});

app.controller('SiblingOneCtrl',
  function SiblingOneCtrl ($scope) {

  $scope.$emit('child', 'Some data'); // going up!

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But is it also possible if the controllers weren't in the same file?

Comment: Yes it is possible even if it is not in the same file.

Comment: Put one of the controller in one file and other controller in another file. It will work if both the controller are loaded by the angular.